# How to Check a value in dictionary before returning in Lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Result json is below

```
result = {'took': 5, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
```

I need to check `result['hits']['total']['value']` is `0` or `!0`

Local code is working fine and it is below

```
if result['hits']['total']['value']!=0:
    print (result)
elif result['hits']['total']['value']==0
    print ('no values to print ')
```

In Lambda its throwing syntax error

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    result = {'took': 5, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
    print (result)
    if result['hits']['total']['value'] != 0:
        return {
            'body':result
               }
    elif result['hits']['total']['value']=0
        return{
            'body': json.dumps('No values found!')
        }
```

Comment: `elif result['hits']['total']['value'] == 0`?

Comment: @Rakesh I tried already?

Comment: Which line comes up to be syntax error?

Comment: @MT-FreeHK  elif result['hits']['total']['value'] == 0

Comment: You forgot to put `:` in the sentence `elif result['hits']['total']['value'] == 0`

Comment: @BradFigueroa new to lambda sorry for troubling the time.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question because it was caused by typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should the below syntax, the `:` was missing from the end of your elif statement, this must always be included.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    result = {'took': 5, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
    print (result)
    if result['hits']['total']['value'] != 0:
        return {
            'body':result
               }
    elif result['hits']['total']['value'] == 0:
        return{
            'body': json.dumps('No values found!')
        }
```